# computing the divisor of a differential

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

[image]

I have some trouble to computer the divisor of a differential in the subject of algebraic curve. Any feedback is greatly appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Hint: $dx=\dfrac{2y\,dy}{f'(x)}$.